# On Mac OS 11.4 Big Sur, how to remove old apple id from app store, that is associated with XPS Reader?

Tags: apple-id, mac-appstore

I bought a used macbook from another person. I have everywhere (seemingly) set up my apple id, for game center, apple id, etc, but sometimes I can still see some remnants from the old user which is another email. Specifically, when I try to update an app (XPS Reader) from app store, I get popup with message[image]

but this is not my email. My apple id is another one. How to remove this old one? Consider that I have already installed some apps, XCode, even the Big Sur I have installed without problems. But sometimes this pops up. Any advice. OS is Big Sur , Mac OS 11.4, macbook pro retina mid-2014, 2,6 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5

Comment: It is possible that some of the existing apps on your MB are installed using a third Apple ID. In such a case, locating and removing such apps and reinstalling them under your own Apple ID might help. Sorry, but I don't know how you can locate such apps, if any. Of course, you can do a clean reinstall but I reckon this is not something you wish to do.

Comment: You should completely erase a Mac before use, so you avoid any legacy from its previous user. They should have done this before sale. Right now not even the OS itself strictly belongs to you. The previous owner should have done this & other tasks before selling it. See [What to do before you sell, give away, or trade in your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201065)